# Mess with set theory

Tags: elementary-set-theory

There are 3 sets $A$, $B$ and $C$ included in $U$ such that:

\begin{cases}
C\cap A =C &  \\ 
n(C)^{c}=150 \\ 
n(A^{c}\cap B^{c} ) ^{c}=90\\ 
n[(A\cup B)-C] =6n(C)\\
n(U)=?
\end{cases}

Help with set theory problem

edit: $n$ = cardinality
n(U) = Number of elements in the universe

Comment: What does $n$ denote?

Comment: @B.Mehta From the context, $n()$ is the size measure.

Comment: What the heck is $n(\cup)$???

Comment: I would guess it's meant to be $n(U)$.

Comment: @Susana So, Susana, what have you tried and where is this problem giving you trouble?  You get better response if you include your own work.

Comment: If I knew how to start I would do it

Comment: http://s2.subirimagenes.com/imagen/previo/thump_9750562tc.png???

Comment: For those confused, many "finite math" texts use $n(S)$ to denote $|S|$.

Comment: Your image @Susana has two circles labeled $B$ and has $C$ as a larger circle than it probably should be.  What does $C\cap A=C$ imply about the relationship between $C$ and $A$?

Comment: $(A^c\cap B^c)^c$ equals $A\cup B$, for a start. $C\cap A=C$ is the same as $C\subseteq A$; this should tell you what shape your Venn diagram should look like. (Technically it's actually called an "Euler diagram" if it's a different 'shape' but whatever)

Comment: Also n (S) = I S I = #S

Comment: (Error: the inner B should be A, C∩A = C => A is a subset of C

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'll only provide a sketch and leave you to fill in the details.

First here's a handy counting formula that I always show my finite math students. For two sets $S$ and $T$,

$$ |S \setminus T | = |S| - |S \cap T| $$

where I write $S \setminus T$ instead of $S - T$ to represent the collection of objects that are in $S$ but not in $T$.

You should also know that if $S \cap T = S$, then $S \subseteq T$, and that $(S^C \cap T^C)^C = S \cup T$, by de Morgan's laws.

Now let's get to counting. Condition 2 says that

$$|U| - |C| = 150$$

Condition 3 says $$|A \cup B| = |A| + |B| - |A \cap B| = 90$$

or that

$$|(A^C \cap B^C)^C| = |U| - |A \cup B| = 90$$

Finally condition 4 says

\begin{align*}
|(A \cup B) \setminus C| &= |A \cup B| - |(A \cup B) \cap C| \\
&= |A \cup B| - |(A \cap C) \cup (B \cap C)| \\
&= 6|C|
\end{align*}

where I have used the distributive property of intersection over union. Now it's just up to some clever algebra.

Comment: I do not clarify with the venn diagram, help please

Answer (score 0):

**Hint**: Draw a Venn diagram of the sets.

Comment: I think this is more "comment-grade helpful" than "answer-grade helpful."

Comment: **I think this is more "comment-grade helpful" than "answer-grade helpful ** ???

Comment: I do not clarify with the venn diagram, help please